# Display the date modified of a file in another directory?

Tags: date, ls

I want to display the date modified of a file that is in another directory.

e.g. I am in `/some/directory` and I `grep -rHl "foo"` which returns a list of files.  I am curious about the date modified of `/a/completely/different/directory/result.txt` without having to go to that directory and list the files.

Can this be done?

Comment: `stat -c %y /path/to/file`

Comment: @urcodebetterznow Don't you want to add an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use `stat` from GNU Coreutils:

```
stat -c %y /path/to/file
```

output:

```
2020-12-08 15:43:01.306251716 +0100
```

Or `ls` from GNU Coreutils:

```
ls --full-time /path/to/file
```

output:

```
rw------- 1 user user 759 2020-12-08 15:43:01.306251716 +0100 /path/to/file
```